# How to group seconds in minutes in pandas dateframe

Tags: python, pandas, date, dataframe, timedelta

Right now I have in seconds and I want to group by minute. I know I need to modify it, but I'm not sure how.

My seconds are something like this:

```
2017-08-18 23:59:35+02:00                     -45.40   
2017-08-18 23:59:36+02:00                     -69.00   
2017-08-18 23:59:37+02:00                     -35.00   
2017-08-18 23:59:38+02:00                      -1.00   
2017-08-18 23:59:39+02:00                      33.00
```

**Any ideas?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If 'qh' is the time column in the dataframe you wish to group by minutes, you can set this as the index:

```
df.set_index('qh', inplace=True)
```

Then you can resample (group) the index by minutes and get the values out as a Series. Here I just sum the values:

```
output = df['values'].resample('1Min').sum()
```

Comment: qh is not the index. My index is as how it shows there is no name for it

Comment: So gh is a column in the index? If so, just set the index as shown

Comment: Works perfectly, actually